# How to pass options into Express template engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using [EJS](https://www.ejs.co) to [render my templates on my Express.js server](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

EJS has options you can pass into the standard methods, one of which being the `async` option. I'd like to use that option with Express.

I tried to do the following:

```
app.set("view options", {"async": true});
```

But that created problems with Express just returning `{}`, which is really strange.

How can I tell Express to pass in the `async` option into EJS using the least code possible?

I really don't want to do a massive refactor, so although I could rewrite all my code to using the `ejs.renderFile` method, I really want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Try :: app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); app.locals.async = true;

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Hmm. That produced the same problem with returning `{}`. No idea why that'd be happening.

Comment: Following document https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express